# Parsing env files

Tags: python, python-3.x, secret-key

How do safely store passwords and API keys within an `.env` file and properly parse them? using python?

I want to store passwords that I do not wish to push into public repos.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may parse the key values of an `.env` file you can use `os.getenv(key)` where you replace `key` with the key of the value you want to access

Suppose the contents of the `.env` files are :

```
A=B
FOO=BAR
SECRET=VERYMUCH
```

You can parse the content like this :

```py
import os

print(os.getenv("A"))
print(os.getenv("FOO"))
print(os.getenv("SECRET"))
# And so on...
```

Which would result in (output / stdout) :

```
B
BAR
VERYMUCH
```

Now, if you are using git version control and you never want yourself to push an environment file accidentally then add this to your `.gitignore` file and they'll be conveniently ignored.

```
.env
```

(Although you should make your life a bit easier by using an existing [`.gitignore`](https://github.com/github/gitignore) template all of which by default ignore `.env` files)

Lastly :

1. you can load `.env` just like a text file by doing :

```py
with open(".env") as env:
    ...
```

and then proceed to manually parse it using regex

2. In case for some reason if `.env` files aren't detected by your python script then use this module [python-dotenv](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/)

You may make use of the aforementioned library like this :

```py
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()  # take environment variables from .env.

# Code of your application, which uses environment variables (e.g. from `os.environ` or
# `os.getenv`) as if they came from the actual environment.
```